# Getting the week number for a date (week starting on Wednesday)

Tags: java, java-8, week-number

```
LocalDate initial = LocalDate.now();
DayOfWeek dayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.WEDNESDAY;
WeekFields weekFields = WeekFields.of(dayOfWeek, 1);
int weekNo = date.get(weekFields.weekOfWeekBasedYear());
System.out.println("Week No"+weekNo);
```

I am using the above code for date 2018-07-29. I expect week no 30, but I get 31.

What am I missing here to get the result of 30?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you expected output as according to [ISO-8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601), where [current week](https://www.epochconverter.com/weeknumbers) is [week 30](https://www.epochconverter.com/weeks/2018), you'd need to follow this:

> Week number according to the ISO-8601 standard, weeks starting on Monday. The first week of the year is the week that contains that year's first Thursday (='First 4-day week').

This is implemented by [`WeekFields.ISO`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/WeekFields.html#ISO).

If instead, you want the week to start on `WEDNESDAY`, you only need to change the `minimalDaysInFirstWeek` from `1` to `4` (='First 4-day week'):

```
LocalDate date = LocalDate.now();
WeekFields weekFields = WeekFields.of(DayOfWeek.WEDNESDAY, 4);
int weekNo = date.get(weekFields.weekOfWeekBasedYear());
System.out.println("Week No " + weekNo);
```